# scale_color_manual() for different geoms in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)

delta <- tibble(
  type = c("alpha", "beta", "gamma"), 
  a = rnorm(3, 5), 
  b = rnorm(3, 6)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(delta = abs(a - b)) %>% 
  gather(`a`, `b`, `delta`, key = "letter", value = "value")


ggplot(delta %>% filter(letter != "delta"), aes(type, value, fill = letter)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
  geom_col(data = delta %>% filter(letter == "delta"), width = 0.5) + 
  scale_color_manual("grey", "black", "blue")
```

I'd like the `a` and `b` bars to be grey and black. And the `delta` bar to be blue. How do I do this with `scale_color_manual()`? Seems my syntax above is off.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two things that need to be changed:

1. Since you've used `fill = letter`, you should use `scale_fill_manual` instead of `scale_color_manual` (which would have been appropriate if you had used `color = letter`).
2. The manual color `values` should be provided as a **vector**.

```r
library(tidyverse)

delta <- tibble(
  type = c("alpha", "beta", "gamma"), 
  a = rnorm(3, 5), 
  b = rnorm(3, 6)
) %>% 
  mutate(delta = abs(a - b)) %>% 
  gather(`a`, `b`, `delta`, key = "letter", value = "value")


ggplot(delta %>% filter(letter != "delta"), aes(type, value, fill = letter)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
  geom_col(data = delta %>% filter(letter == "delta"), width = 0.5) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey", "black", "blue"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-10-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>